# PDF сделать ссылкой

Tags: html, pdf

Есть каталог с картинкой и текстом в pdf. Он размещен на сайте. Можно ли сделать картинки и текст ссылками на страницу поиска с данным артикулом. Чтобы клиент кликнул на картинку или текст, попал на страницу поиска с соответствующим артикулом.
Вкратце, нужно, чтобы в pdf документе некоторые картинки и текст стали ссылками на какой-то сайт.

И как на это смотреть с точки зрения инет-программирования? Делают так? Или другой вариант предложите?

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. вы хотите, чтобы в вашем pdf документе некоторые картинки и текст стали ссылками на какой-то сайт?

Comment: приечем тут инет программирование. действительно, можно внедрить линки в pdf документ, просто и хорошо работает. Для этого необязательно, чтоб pdf лежал на сайте, все равно будет переходить по ссылке

Comment: и как, подскажите пожалуйста? какие средства использовать. Нашла вот эту статью http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf
но не понимаю, какие инструменты надо использовать?

Comment: если от адоба, то профессиональную версию акробата, а не ридер. Или вы имеете в виду, какие кнопочки нажимать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

знание программирования тут ни к чему. достаточно стандартных инструментов программы для создания/редактирования PDF.

вот ссылка на официальное руководство от Adobe: [Создание ссылок](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/acrobat/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7cb8.w.html)

> Ссылки позволяют выполнять переход к другим местам того же документа, к другим электронным документам, в том числе вложениям, и к веб-сайтам. Ссылки можно использовать, чтобы запускать действия или обеспечивать читателю немедленный доступ к нужной информации.

Comment: спасибо, какая прога?

Comment: Acrobat от компании Adobe. я уверен, аналогичный функционал есть в аналогичных программах, например от Foxit. если мой ответ вам подходит, отметьте его принятым нажатием на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. а если каталог большой. Не будешь же каждый раз ссылку делать в пдф. Может другие пути есть? Или скачать картинки  с каталога, присвоить им нужный артикул  и разместить в базе. Просто каталог часто меняется, а картинки остаются. Посоветуйте, плиз...

Comment: если большое кол-во картинок надо постоянно менять, то конечно неудобно каждый раз обновлять пдф. но тогда надо менять подход, например, не использовать пдф для этих целей. либо делать пдф шаблонным, чтобы замена контента не занимала много времени. возможно, вам будет удобно использовать CMS для постоянного обновления ваших продуктов - но это уже совсем другая история)

Comment: у меня есть битрикс. Как понять , пдф делать шаблонным, если нам присылают поставщики, значит нет. Этот способ не подойдет.